# TypeError: "method" is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

I'm currently trying to develop a small game in NodeJS to learn ES6.
I created a "Player" object with the new syntax. The static functions work perfectly. However, calling its methods throws a TypeError

> (ex : TypeError: socket.handshake.session.player.joinRoom is not a function).

I don't understand why because I did the same thing I saw on several tutorials. Since joinRoom is a setter, I tried to add 'set' before the declaration but I got the same problem. Here's my code

Player.js

```js
class Player{
    constructor(name){
        this.id = Player.setID()
        this.name = name
        this.currentRoom = ""
        this.isOwner = false
        this.cards = {}

        Player.list[this.id] = this
    }

    joinRoom(code){
        this.currentRoom = code
    }
    makeOwner(){
        this.isOwner = true
    }
    static setID(){
        if(Player.list.length === 0){
            return 1
        }else{
            return Player.list[Player.list.length - 1].id + 1
        }
    }
}

Player.list = []

module.exports = Player
```

app.js

```js
// socket.handshake.session.player is initialized with "new Player(playerName)" 
socket.on("creatingroom", function(maxPlayers){
    console.log(socket.handshake.session.player)
    // Returns {id: 1, name: 'chosenName', currentRoom: '', isOwner: false, cards: {}}
    var room = new Room(maxPlayers)
    socket.handshake.session.player.joinRoom(room.code)
    socket.handshake.session.player.makeOwner()
})
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I do have the feeling `.session.player` got serialized & deserialized somewhere.

Comment: Try logging `socket.handshake.session.player`

Comment: As @JonasWilms said, use `typeof` to check `socket.handshake.session.player` and make sure it's an object. Then check the `player` object itself to make sure that the `Player` prototype methods weren't pruned off - you can also just check `Player.prototype.isPrototypeOf(socket.handshake.session.player)`

Comment: Thanks for you answers, So, JonasWilms and @zfrisch were right, socket.handshake.session.player is an object, but not a Player, that's why I couldn't call the methods.

Answer (score 2):

While the object you are working with seems to have all the properties of the  player, it looks as if it does not inherit from the Player class. You could create a new Player from that object though :

```
const player = Object.assign(new Player('Name'), socket.handshake.session.player);
player.joinRoom(12);
player.makeOwner();
console.log(player);
```

Now as `player` is a real Player instance, you can now call methods on it.

Comment: You're solution might not work for my situation because I have a list of the Player, and making a new Player adds an entry to the list. So since got the player's ID, I can get the player's object with Player.list[id]. I don't know if it's the cleanest solution, but I guess it'll work

Comment: @yassine it would be good to know what that `socket` refers to ... then we might find the root cause of this ...